# Post object to a WCF method

Tags: wcf, restsharp

I am a newbie to both RestSharp and WCF and I am trying to write a working sample that has a post method which takes a string and an object as parameters. I have looked at another post here where someone asked the same question and I still couldn't get it to work. Can someone please point me in the right direction. I debugged the code and I am getting a `null` in the object. It seems like its pretty straight forward but I am not sure what I am missing. This is what I have so far.

Server side:

```
[OperationContract]
        [Description("addUser")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/addUser?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        TSCRUResponse addUser(string id, User usr);


 public TSCRUResponse addUser(string id, User usr)
        {
            TSCRUResponse r = new TSCRUResponse();
            r.status =  id + usr.name + usr.age + usr.gender;
            return r;
        }
```

The first parameter for the above method comes through OK but not the object.

These are the objects:

```
[DataContract]
    public class TSCRUResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "age")]
        public string age { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
        public string gender { get; set; }
    }
```

Client side :

```
public void postmethod(string uri)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:1119/TestService.svc/";
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("addUser?id={id}", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.JsonSerializer();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("id", "12839", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            User itm = new User { age = "40", name = "user1", gender = "M" };
            request.AddBody(itm);

            var response = client.Execute<TSCRUResponse>(request);
            TSCRUResponse addres = response.Data;
            Console.WriteLine(addres.status);
        }
```